Quickly computing product of Householder reflections $\prod_{v} I - v v^T$
I'm looking to speed up computation of the following quantity for a list of $d$ vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^d$
$$A=\prod_v I - v v^T$$
This is just a product of Householder reflections, and naive ways of computing this matrix in Mathematica seem orders of magnitudes slower than, say, finding QRDecomposition $A$ which is also a product of $d$ Householder reflections, any tips to get this computation to a similar level of performance?
d = 400;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
isotropic = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];
A = Dot @@ Table[ii - {v}\[Transpose] . {v}, {v, isotropic}] // 
  Timing // First

Background: simulations for this question

Would an approximation work? Since it looks like A is very diagonal, we can approximate it as DiagonalMatrix[Times @@ (1 - isotropic^2)] (since that is the product of the diagonals of each $I - vv^T$. Sorry if this isn't super helpful. You always ask questions that I find very interesting, but never feel quite equipped to understand.

Here's a way to do what you ask and @Henrik Schumacher's variant with LAPACK routines:
d = 400;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
isotropic = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];

amat = Dot @@ Table[ii - {v}\[Transpose] . {v}, {v, isotropic}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
(*  0.350009  *)

cmat = N@IdentityMatrix[d];
Do[LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`LARF["R", vec, 1., cmat], {vec, isotropic}] //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
(*  0.014626  *)

amat - cmat // Abs // Max
(*  1.36002*10^-14  *)

Henrik's good advice given in his answer can be implemented as follows. There seems to a difference in the order of multiplication, but it's easy to sort out. The difference in timing between Mathematica and LAPACK is not so great here.
uvec = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d];
cvec = {uvec};
Do[LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`LARF["R", vec, 1., cvec],
 {vec, Reverse@isotropic}] //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
auFast = ApplyHouseHolder[isotropic, uvec]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

(*
0.000459
0.001021
*)

First@cvec - auFast // Abs // Max
(*  1.22125*10^-15  *)

As is typical with LAPACK routines, it overwrites the C matrix/vector.

Cool. (+1 of course). I am not overly surprised that LAPACK is only little faster. After all this is just a "BLAS level 2" routine ( outer products of vectors and --- if cvec is indeed a matrix --- matrix-vector products). The real software engineering starts at "BLAS level 3". I guess the optimization here comes from fusing KroneckerProduct with the subtraction via the the dger BLAS routine.

Thanks! Referenced this post in https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3345575?p_p_auth=X4ZSuNB5

The point of rank-one-perturbations of the identity is that you never form that actual matrix. That is an algorithmic restriction, but it can be exploited quite often. The BFGS optimization algorithm is a typicaly example for this. Instead of creating the matrix A, we can implement its action of vectors as follows:
ApplyHouseHolder[V_?MatrixQ, u_?VectorQ] := Module[{w, v},
   w = u;
   Do[
    v = V[[i]];
    w -= v v . w;
    , {i, Length[V], 1, -1}];
   w
   ];

Here a usage example:
d = 400;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
isotropic = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];

u = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d];

A = Dot @@ Table[ii - {v}\[Transpose] . {v}, {v, isotropic}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

AuTrue = A . u;
AuFast = ApplyHouseHolder[isotropic, u]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[AuTrue - AuFast]]


0.318342
0.00064
1.84297*10^-14

Note that forming the matrix ii - {v}\[Transpose] . {v} takes $O(d^2)$ time and memory and dotting two such matrices requires alread $O(d^3)$ time. So, in your example, forming A costs $O(d^4)$. In constrast, ApplyHouseHolder[isotropic, u] needs only $O(d^2)$ time and $O(d)$ memory.
If you really, really need the product matrix (e.g., some applications of the QR decomposition might require this), then you can do it in $O(d^3)$ time and $O(d^2)$ memory as follows:
HouseHolderMatrix[V_?MatrixQ] := Module[{n, d, A, v},
   {n, d} = Dimensions[V];
   A = IdentityMatrix[d, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision] - KroneckerProduct[V[[1]], V[[1]]];
   Do[
    A -= KroneckerProduct[V[[i]], V[[i]] . A];
    , {i, Length[V] - 1, 1, -1}];
   A
   ];

Beware: KroneckerProduct[V[[i]], V[[i]] . A] costs only $O(d^2)$, while KroneckerProduct[V[[i]], V[[i]]] . A costs only $O(d^3)$.

Thanks! Referenced this post in https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3345575?p_p_auth=X4ZSuNB5
